# Error not showing when error in razor view aspnet core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

When I add a call on viewComponent in a view and the viewComponent not working, there are not error message, the razor view skip the viewComponent in render and show the rest, but I don't no why the viewComponent not working.

In previous version MVC 5, when there are an error in razor view, the exception was throw, how to make the equivalent in aspnet core ?

Answer (score -2):

> At this point, if you try and go to /home/index you’ll get a nasty
>   shock, nothing will appear, just a blank page.
>
> Before you tear your hair out trying to work out why, let me save you
>   the hassle. There are two more steps you need to take.
>
> Firstly, Core will attempt to compile the razor views at runtime and
>   fails unless you add a setting to your project.json file.

```
"buildOptions": {
  "preserveCompilationContext": true,
  "debugType": "portable",
  "emitEntryPoint": true
},
```

> preserveCompilationContext ensures that various reference assemblies
>   (e.g. System) are preserved so that Core can compile your razor views
>   at runtime.
>
> Secondly, you need to tell your Core app where to start looking for
>   content files (e.g. views). You can specify this by setting the
>   UseContentRoot() option in Program.cs.

```
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

            host.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

> Try hitting the page again now and you will see your rendered view.

Comment: Seems like the primary (and possibly only) question he was asking was how to show the errors.